# Continuity implies analyticity

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:** Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{C}$ which is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{it\in\mathbb{C}:t\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Then is $f$ analytic on whole $\mathbb{C}$?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: yes - in this case you can use either Cauchy (write $f=f_1+f_2$ on a disc centered at some fix $it_0$ of some fixed radius say $1$, where $f_1,f_2$ are the Cauchy integrals of $f$ on the left part of the circle plus the real segment and the right part plus the real segment, so one represents $f$ in the left semidisc and is zero in the right, the other the reverse, while when you add them, the real segment part integrals cancel out by opposite orientation, so you represent $f$ there by a Cauchy integral too) or Morera to prove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, if we can prove that the function has antiderivative on the whole complex plane, we can take advantage of Morera theorem to conclude.

Let $\gamma_{z_1,z_2} (t)= (1-t)z_1 +tz_2$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, linear path from $z_1$ to $z_2$.

For any $z$ we define function $F$ as follows:

$$ F(z) =\int_{\gamma_{0,z}} f $$

If $z\not\in \{it \mid t\in \mathbf{R} \}=:L$, let $z_1 \in B(z,r)$, where $r=d(z,  L)>0  $. Then, by Cauchy theorem (on triangles suffices) on path $$\gamma_{0,z}\cup\gamma_{z,z_1}\cup\gamma_{z_1,0},$$ we get
$$ F(z_1) - F(z) = \int_{\gamma_{z,z_1}} f, $$
which leads to $F^\prime(z) = f(z)$, as

$$ \lim_{z_1\rightarrow z} \int_{\gamma_{z,z_1}} f = (z_1-z)\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_{0}^1 f((1-t)z+tz_1)dt =(z_1-z)f(z). $$

Cases $z\in L\setminus \{0\}$ and $z=0$, can be obtained from direct calculation of the derivative (using the limit fact above which is based only on the continuity of $f$ on the whole plane).

*Note:* This can be generalized to a [star domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) from which we remove a finite number of lines passing trough the vantage point.